# VBA Excel - проверка на нулевые цифры до и после определённых цифр числа

Tags: excel, vba, числа

Возьмём число в пределах от 1 до 1 000 000 **000** 000 000, где жирным шрифтом для примера выделен класс разрядов числа, который будем проверять. Необходимо проверить условие, при котором классы до него (тысячи и единицы) являются пустыми. Отдельно необходимо проверить условие, при котором пустыми являются классы после выделенного (миллиарды, триллионы и квадриллионы). Если первое условие истинно, а второе нет, результат должен быть истинным, в противном случае ложным. Проблема в том, что у меня не получается сделать цикл этого кода для всех классов разрядов.
Число мы поделили на классы примерно вот так:

```
For i1 = 1 To 6 'i1 - номер класса разрядов справа налево
x = Fix(x) / 1000 'x - исходное число
y(i1) = (x - Fix(x)) * 1000 'y(i1) - группа цифр в каждом классе
Next
```

Классы поделили на разряды вот так:

```
For i2 = 1 To 6 'i2 - номер класса разрядов справа налево
y1 = y(i2) Mod 10 'y1 - цифра разряда сотен каждого класса
y2 = (y(i2) - y1) / 10 Mod 10 'y2 - цифра разряда десятков каждого класса
y3 = y(i2) \ 100 'y3 - цифра разряда единиц каждого класса
Next
```

На примере числа 1 235 000 687 000 000 должно получиться вот это:

**fffttt**

На примере числа 225 485:

**ffffft**

На примере числа 200 000:

**ffffft**

и т. д.

Comment: Почему и для 6-значнх, и для 16-значного чисел одинаковое количество проверок - 6?

Comment: Потому что не следует забывать о классах и разрядах, которые ещё не использованы в числах меньше, чем в 16 цифр. А проверки относятся к классам разрядов, а не к отдельным цифрам

Comment: Все равно непонятно... Если <16 разрядов, но больше 6? Покажите пример в `Excel` с десятком-другим значений. На одном-двух примерах покажите проверку пошагово, иначе будет так же, как в предыдущем вопросе (куча уточнений, потом удаление вопроса автором)

Comment: Возьмём число 1 235 000 687 000 000. Оно имеет следующую структуру: _00_ 1 235 000 687 000 000. Нули, выделенные курсивом - это цифры, не используемые в числе. В этой структуре каждая группа из трёх цифр, разделённая пробелами, соответствует одной из двух букв: **f** или **t** (соответственно, _ложь_ и _истина_). Таким образом, **f-f-f-t-t-t**. В числе 200 000 структура будет выглядеть уже вот так: _000 000 000 000_ 200 000, а значит, **f-f-f-f-f-t**.

Comment: Но если число, например, 1 235 202 000. Сколько здесь проверок?! 4 (для каждого класса) или 10-12 (для каждого разряда). Неужели трудно составить небольшой пример (о нем - в комментарии выше) и показать на него ссылку? Как будто это надо кому-то, а не Вам.

Comment: Всегда 6 проверок для каждого класса. Число 1 235 202 000 имеет структуру _000 000 00_ 1 235 202 000

Comment: Вот! Наконец-то ИСТИНА! Четкая формулировка - 50% решения. Для первого/последнего разряда всего числа (не класса) принимаем, что правый/левый разряд (которого фактически нет) равен нулю? Т.е. для числа 123 структура такая: 0 **0**00 000 000 000 000 12**3** 0. Для старшего класса всегда false, правильно? А зачем Вы делили на разряды, они как-то влияют на решение?

Comment: Для старшего класса всегда получается false. А на разряды я делил, потому что у меня в коде так предусмотрено для дальнейшей проверки, которую я в этом вопросе пока не рассматриваю.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
    Const x As Double = 1234567

    Debug.Print fCheckClasses(x)
End Sub

Function fCheckClasses(x As Double) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 3 To Len(x & "") Step 3
        If Int(x Mod 10 ^ i) > 0 Then Exit For
    Next i
    
    If i >= Len(x & "") Then i = i - 3
    i = i / 3
    fCheckClasses = Left$("ffffff", 6 - i) & Left$("ttttt", i)
End Function
```

Может, достаточно определения `i` и не нужно `String` рисовать?

Comment: А есть способ проверять каждый класс по отдельности в одном коде? У меня так в коде предусмотрено

Comment: Я в том смысле, что если б был способ проверять через If _класс соответствует обоим условиям_ Then _переменная_ = True а потом If _переменная_ = True Then _соответствующий символ_ = "t", Else  _соответствующий символ_ = "f"

Comment: >> *А есть способ проверять каждый класс по отдельности в одном коде?* Так и есть: на каждом шаге цикла проверяем один класс. Зачем два условия, если достаточно одного?

Comment: Ну как одно условие: типа два в одном: все классы справа нулевые и хотя бы один класс слева не нулевой

Comment: Если Вы знаете, что к магазину дорога ведет прямо, станете Вы проверять обратную дорогу? Для чего проверять то, без чего можно спокойно обойтись? Хотите, добавьте проверку  сравнение с нулем `x - Int(x Mod 10 ^ i)`. Но лишнее это!

Comment: Я по поводу того кода с переводом числа в текст на иностранном языке. Необходимо пометить самый левый класс, соответствующий символу "t", прежде чем впоследствии в тексте отображались другие слова, соответствующие этому классу

Comment: То Вам текст нужен, то номер класса... переменная i указывает на такой класс, первый слева. И в ответе написано об этом

Comment: Объясню попроще: необходимо извлечь эту самую переменную i, и с её помощью вывести число и в нём классы, соответствующие условиям, выделить жирным шрифтом

Comment: А это уже совершенно не по теме... Ответ по вопросу получен.  Не валите все в одну кучу.

Comment: Я лишь пытаюсь отобразить результат несколько по-другому